# Command Line on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to programming and using python. I am unable to use the terminal to use command-line work. I can run script, but nothing from the command line

I cannot even do print('hello'), though I can do that on idle

I have reviewed some tutorials, but they are of no help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about VS Code built-in terminal (Ctrl+`), before execute `print('hello')`  or some similar code, you should first start Python interective session by typing in `python` and hitting `Enter`.

Check [this link](https://realpython.com/run-python-scripts/#how-to-run-python-code-interactively) for more details.

Comment: thanks for the link: "python3" works!!